# Very unproductive while offline; anything I can do to be productive again?

Tags: development-environment

I write code while traveling, and I almost always use cafe (but sometimes on a room in AirBnB).

However, the problem is that too often the Wi-Fi at cafe is awful, either too unstable to keep connecting, or too often to get a server error. In many times I even could not connect to the Wi-Fi.

Another painstaking, yet more predictable case is on the flight. The Wi-Fi doesn't exist practically.

So in these cases, I must write code without any network. How can I be productive enough in these situations, or at least mitigate the inefficiency?

My primary field is either on iOS/Swift or Data Science/Python/R, and less likely on Web/node.js.

I tried Stack Overflow's offline archive but it is too slow, and takes up so much storage so I decided to give it up.

I usually end up using my smartphone and see SNS while waiting for the regain of the network. Sometimes I search on iPhone's Safari but it is too much of a pain to use it, especially browse through GitHub (Stack Overflow is relatively fine). Sometimes I switch to tethering, but only when I'm in a country where mobile carriers provide unlimited data.

Are there any tips and tricks to mitigate the inefficiency?

Comment: I'd like to answer this (and plan to) but i do want to clarify one thing before i do. This coding work, is it for a job? Or is what you do on the road just personal/passion projects?

Comment: Your question is off-topic on this site, but it might be suited for https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ (but before asking there, check their site rules first, and check it is not a duplicate).

Comment: @DocBrown it would be explicitly off-topic over there: "**[Questions require a goal that we can address.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)**  Rather than explaining the difficulties of your situation, explain what you want to do to make it better. For more information, see [this meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696)...

Comment: @gnat: IMHO the goal of the OP is clearly written in this question, what do you miss?

Comment: "goal that we can address..." @DocBrown - in Q&A format, this is explained in their meta referred in my prior comment

Comment: @gnat: sorry, but I don't get it. I read that meta post, it asked for a clear goal and what the OP already tried. This question has a stated clear goal: how to mitigate working inefficiencies when being offline. And the OP told us what he already tried. So again: what do you miss?

Answer (score 1):

First learn and use git - the need to be able to do real work and version the results on long plane rides was what triggered it's invention.

Second download, *or purchase*, the reference material for the languages & tools that you are using in ebook format or the like, *worst case good, searchable, PDF files will do*. Learn to use these primary references more *rather than turning to Google & SO as the first place to look*. These will include, in your case, the python language manual & library reference but obviously you will also need the references for any packages that you regularly use.

Third get into the habit of taking an offline copy of any ticketing or problem reporting system that you use - a long journey without online resources is a perfect time to address all of those bug reports that you have been meaning to get around to.